# macOS suppresses ^ Control -1 through 4 shortcuts

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings

Does anyone know how can I make <kbd>⌃ Control</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> to <kbd>⌃ Control</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> shortcuts usable?

I've disabled them via *System > Keyboard > Mission Control*, and yet, macOS doesn't allow those keybindings to be processed by other apps.

Interestingly, <kbd>⌃ Control</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd> ... <kbd>0</kbd> work fine. I guess it has something to do with number of virtual screens I have?

How can I make these shortcuts available for assignment.

Update1: Apparently that's the issue of the Chrome on macOS. The system can assign custom hotkeys via keyboard -> app shortcuts, but the browses itself cant pass ctrl + number hotkey through.

Comment: Have you tried re-enabling temporarily so you can change them to something else?